# log4j Logging file unable to write messages in multi module project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, logging

My current project structure looks like this:

```
Plugin-JAR
   -------- src/main/java
            --- com.edu.package
            --- Java Class


Plugin-WAR
   -------- src/main/resources
            ---- log4j.properties

Plugin-Parent
   -------- Plugin-JAR
   -------- Plugin-WAR
   -------- pom.xml
```

`Plugin-WAR` has `<packaging>` of war while `Plugin-JAR` has `jar` packaging. `Plugin-JAR` has been added as a dependency for `Plugin-WAR`. What I am trying to do is use log4j for logging messages to a log file from Java class in `Plugin-JAR`. I can see the log file created but I am not able to make Java class log messages to that log file.

Another thing that I have tried is keeping `log4j.properties` file in `src/main/resources` in `Plugin-JAR` and the have the `pom.xml` in `Plugin-WAR` include `src/main/resources` as a `<resource>`. In that case it doesn't even create the log file.

What am I doing wrong? It is my first time working with multi-module projects. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: can you tell us about your log4j.properties

Answer (score -2):

I solved the problem. It wasnt related to folder structure. It was a change in server configuration that was needed. Nothing to do with folder structure.

Comment: What change? As it is this answer is not helpful to anyone.